# Cypress test exit test cases after redirecting to external login

Tags: single-sign-on, integration-testing, cypress, end-to-end, app-id

my application is using IBM w3 login authentication  https://preprod.login.w3.ibm.com/
if I'm trying to hit my base URL `cy.visit('/baseuRl')` it redirects to  `https://preprod.login.w3.ibm.com/` w3 login to authenticate me.
after redirecting back to my application I found cypress exists
it there any workaround to bypass w3-Auth handle it?

Comment: The issue might be caused because of using different domains like described here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security#Same-superdomain-per-test

Comment: I'm not familiar with this IBM login, but do you know if it's technically possible to log in via request instead of the UI? This is a commonly chosen solution in conjunction with Cypress and other platforms, e.g. here for Azure AD: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64822167/6135684 or here for Salesforce: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514609/how-do-i-login-to-salesforce-by-using-cypress

Comment: thanks for your response, and yes I did what you just mentioned 
I handled the login programmatically before stating cypress test